# if value already exist in mongodb delete it, else add it to end of the list (mongoengine)

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I use Mongoengine and wanna delete a tag if it exists. If the tag doesnt exist, I want to add it. But my code is not really working.

```
    try:

        Project.objects.filter(literature__oid=id).update_one(
            pull__literature__S__tags=tag_name)
        print("wanna delete "+tag_name)

    except:
        Project.objects.filter(literature__oid=id).update_one(
            push__literature__S__tags=tag_name)
        print("wanna add"+tag_name)
```

this code only deletes the tag from the database but he doesn't jump into the except part if the tag doesn't exist. So he always runs the delete part even if the tag doesn't exist. Is there any other method I could use? I haven't found anything so far...

the tags field of literature is a ListField. So tags looks in mongoDB for example like this:

```
"tags": ["irrelevant", "relevant", "test"]
```

My Models basically look like this:

```
class Literature(EmbeddedDocument):
    oid = ObjectIdField(required=True, default=ObjectId,
                        unique=True, primary_key=True, sparse=True)
    tags = ListField() 

class Project(Document):
    project_name = StringField(unique=True, required=True)
    literature = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Literature))
```

So e.g. I have a literature object with the `oid=1` and an literature object with the `oid=2` and oid=1 has `tags=["irrelevant", "test"]` and oid=2 has `tags =["relevant"]`. I now would like to have the python function:

```
def LiteratureTag(id, tag_name):
    #add tag_name to literature object with the passed id if the tag_name 
    #does't already exist in literature tags and if the tag does exist delete  
    #the tag from the literature object
```

so e.g. if I call `LiteratureTag(1, "relevant")` it should add the tag "relevant" from the literature object with the oid=1 and if I call `LiteratureTag(2, "test")` it should add the tag "test" to the literature object with oid=2. If I call `LiteratureTag(2, "relevant")` the tag "relevant" should get deleted from literature object with oid=2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer that you should not use `try` and `except`. You only go into `except` when your `try` block raises an error. It won't raise an error in your case. You can try to write your code by checking if the tag exists.

Taking your schema into account:

```
class Literature(EmbeddedDocument):
    oid = ObjectIdField(required=True, default=ObjectId,
                        unique=True, primary_key=True, sparse=True)
    tags = ListField() 

class Project(Document):
    project_name = StringField(unique=True, required=True)
    literature = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Literature))
```

I will write my query given your literature id is valid `Object_id`:

```
tag_name=<String> #type string
id=<Object_id> #type objectId


if Project.objects.filter(literature__oid=id,literature__tags__in=[tag_name]):
    #your tag exists, so remove it
    Project.objects.filter(literature__oid=id).update(pull__literature__S__tags=tag_name)
else:
#tag does not exist, push it
    Project.objects.filter(literature__oid=id).update(push__literature__S__tags=tag_name)
```

The above query is totally aligned to your schema.

Comment: I tried the following code but it always jumps into else. ` if Project.objects(Q(literature__S__tags=tag_name) & Q(literature__oid=literature_id)):
        Project.objects.filter(literature__oid=literature_id).update_one(
            pull__literature__S__tags=tag_name)
    else:
        Project.objects.filter(literature__oid=id).update_one(
            push__literature__S__tags=tag_name)
`. Do you know what's wrong with this code? I edited my question with the schema of Project and Literature

Comment: I updated my answer according to the new edited schema you have. I am assuming that you are searching for the tag name. Let me know if this takes you in the right direction.

Comment: actually I dont want to iterate through the entire list of literature. This would take too long. I already have the literature object (for example the id of the object) and then I just want to check if the literature object contains a given string (tag_name) in the tags attribute of the literature object and then pull or add the string from tags

Comment: Since we have id, then we can object to that id. I edited the code.

Comment: Hi, if this answer solved your problem could you please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark on its side? Thanks.

Comment: So this would change my entire models and I can't change the type of the Literature from EmbeddedDocument to Document. If you have any other solution without changing the type of my documents, it would be nice. I'm still struggling with this problem.. sorry btw for the late response

Comment: Hi @Till, I updated the query. It works with your current schema.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not completely working. If there are two literature objects and their object id are e.g. 1 and 2. If literature with id 1 has e.g. the tag "hello" and I wanna add the tag "hello" to literature with the id 2 it's not working. Then python always thinks that he should delete this tag because it already exists in another literature object. I don't know why it's looking into all literature objects and check if any literature object has the tag "hello".  I only can add the tag "hello" to literature with id 2 If I delete the tag "hello" from the other literature object first.

Comment: According to your question, you did not clearly specify it. You wrote 'wanna delete a tag if it exists. If the tag doesnt exist, I want to add it.'

Comment: Can you clarify everything in your question? I have written query according to what you asked in the question. You should add more details about other things in it to totally tell what you are expecting. Thank you. :)

Comment: Also, the query works like this : You give it a literature id and a tag name, it will check if that tag exists in the literature, if yes then it will delete it, else it will add that tag to that literature id.

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry if the question wasn't clear, but for me it was clear that the tag should get added to a literature object also when another literature object already has this tag. Hope the edit makes it more clearly

Comment: According to your latest edit, you have to define two function, one function which deletes the tag and other function which adds the tag. For example : If you do `Literature(1,''irrelevant")` then it will delete the irrelevant tag. What you are trying to achieve here are two different set of works. The example you mentioned, my query does exactly that.  If you put the if and else statement in your `LiteratureTag` function then it will execute that same query given you provide id and tag name to it.

Comment: So I've tried your code but it doesn't add e.g. `tag_name="test` to literature object with `oid=2` if another literature object in `Project` already has this tag. So in this case it wouldn't add `test` to `oid=2` because literature object with `oid=1` already have a `tag="test`. But I actually don't know why.

Comment: And both of these literature id are in one Project document?

Comment: yes. So it basically looks like: `Project--> literature(oid=1, tags="irrelevant";"test");literature(oid=2, tags="relevant");literature(oid=3...);...`

Comment: I noticed that there was syntax problem with the query, I fixed it. It will take tag into account, can you recheck it?

Comment: Still the same problem. If tag exists in other literature object python doesn't go into the `else` part

Comment: You have to make sure that your literature id is also unique, I tested it again on my local, it works.

Comment: Appreciate your help, thanks a lot. Probably I have to find another way :-/